# Is it a good idea to use pwsafe - a password manager not updated since 2005?

Tags: password

I'm looking for a command-line Linux password-manager. It appears that [pwsafe](http://nsd.dyndns.org/pwsafe/) is the program most commonly used. However, its latest update was in 2005. Is it a good idea to use this? Has it been so stable that no updates are necessary, or am I risking using outdated software for an important task like password management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO it would be better to use a plain text file with a structured format and then GPG or OpenSSL encrypt it. Or even just plain `vim` encryption.

The advantage of OpenSSL/GPG over `vim` is that you can decrypt it on the fly and grep the output.

Here's a nice write up for using [vim as a password safe](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Password_Safe_with_Vim_and_OpenSSL).